# Configuring Kestrel on .NET 7.0, but not quite sure how to do it correctly and need some guidance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-7.0

I am a beginner in .NET Core and I am trying to configure a custom domain to be able to use HTTPS for my ASP.NET Core 7.0 Web API.

I was following this guide: [Custom Local Domain using HTTPS, Kestrel & ASP.NET Core](https://dotnetplaybook.com/custom-local-domain-using-https-kestrel-asp-net-core/), but as you can see, he uses .NET Core 3.1 and the structure of the files in the project has changed. In .NET Core 7.0 the `program.cs` and `startup.cs` file have been merged.

Here is my `HostConfig.cs` file:

```
public class HostConfig
{
    public static string CertPath { get; set; }
    public static string CertPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `program.cs` file:

```
using Dot7.API.CRUD.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
{
  HostConfig.CertPath = builder.Configuration["CertPath"];
  HostConfig.CertPassword = builder.Configuration["CertPassword"];
});

builder.Host.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
{
  webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(opt =>
  {
    opt.ListenAnyIP(5000);
    opt.ListenAnyIP(5001, listOpt =>
    {
      listOpt.UseHttps(HostConfig.CertPath, HostConfig.CertPassword);
    });
  });
});

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy("Cors", p =>
  {
    p.AllowAnyOrigin()
          .AllowAnyHeader()
          .AllowAnyMethod();
  });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<databaseContext>(options =>
{
  options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("databaseConnection"));
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseSwagger();
  app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors("Cors");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

When I build and run the application, I get this error message:

> C:\Desktop\dotnet7-vue3-crud - Developpment - HTTPS\Dot7.API.CRUD\Program.cs(19,24): warning CS8604: Possible null reference argument for parameter 'fileName' in 'ListenOptions ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, string fileName, string? password)'. [C:\Desktop\dotnet7-vue3-crud - Developpment - HTTPS\Dot7.API.CRUD\Dot7.API.CRUD.csproj]
>
> Unhandled exception. System.NotSupportedException: ConfigureWebHost() is not supported by WebApplicationBuilder.Host. Use the WebApplication returned by WebApplicationBuilder.Build() instead.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ConfigureHostBuilder.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Infrastructure.ISupportsConfigureWebHost.ConfigureWebHost(Action`1 configure, Action`1 configureOptions)
> at Program.$(String[] args)

I don't really understand what this error message means and how to debug it. Can you somebody help me out?

PS: if you require additional files to inspect the issue, don't hesitate to ask.

I tried looking for Youtube videos, but most of the reference material uses an older version of .NET Core and as a beginner it is not really helpful. I also tried using ChatGPT, but obviously, the answer were outdated and not helpful.

Comment: I think you can configure kestrel from the environment directly...

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `UseKestrel` on `builder.WebHost`:

```cs
builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(opt =>
{
    opt.ListenAnyIP(5000);
    opt.ListenAnyIP(5001, listOpt =>
    {
        listOpt.UseHttps(builder.Configuration["CertPath"],  builder.Configuration["CertPassword"]);
    });
});
```

Note that the approach described in the article with using `HostConfig` with static properties and relying on initialization order is not very idiomatic.

As for warning - check out [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)

Comment: What do you mean by "Note that the approach described in the article with using HostConfig with static properties and relying on initialization order is not very idiomatic." exactly?

Comment: @Oddy I mean that this approach relies on action passed to `ConfigureServices` being called before any actual usage of `HostConfig` static properties. Just read the config in appropriate places.

Comment: I'm a total beginner at dotnet core api application, so I still don't really understand exactly is the issue here. Are you maybe suggesting that I have the class define directly in the program.cs file?

I also tried replacing my code from builder.Host.ConfigureService... with UseKestrel on builder.WebHost instead but that didn't work. Am I doing something incorrectly here?

Comment: @Oddy if you are a beginner the you don't need to configure kestrel at all. Just create a web app from default template and run it. Do you get the same error when using approach from the answer?

Comment: In the beginning, I simply ran the webapp from the default template with a few API end-points and connect to it via localhost, but now, I need client PCs on my local network to connect to my webapp and use functionalities like the webcam and if I dont configure kestrel, how can they do API calls over HTTPS?

Comment: @Oddy oh, ok. You have not answered my question though - what exception do you get when using my approach.

Comment: Sorry about that, I get a few exception. I can't list all of them, but here are some of them:

 Unhandled exception. System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access denied.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.CertificatePal.FilterPFXStore(ReadOnlySpan`1 rawData, SafePasswordHandle password, PfxCertStoreFlags pfxCertStoreFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.CertificatePal.FromBlobOrFile(ReadOnlySpan`1 rawData, String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)

Comment: @Oddy I would argue that is out of scope of the question. You need to validate that the certificate installed in the same place it is searched for. I can't help you with that ATM.

Comment: Oh, so the error seems to indicate that the certificate cannot be found? or the path is somehow incorrect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254443/discussion-between-oddy-and-guru-stron).